# Migrating system using old components

Tags: sharepoint-online, windows-server, office365apis, windows, exchange-online

I am currently investigating the migration of a system which consists of:
A server which contains - Windows 2012:

- Windows Service communicates with Exchange API to read room availability
- SharePoint 2013 and it's List's to store some booking info which it receives from Outlook API - this part is built in the Windows Service too.

Plan is to make it work with modern infra:
Potentially we do not want a Windows Server involved but it has to work with latest versions of
Office 365 and Exchange APIs.

Can't run it on Windows 10 machines for many different reasons.

Proposal:
I am proposing something that I can build on my own in my team. 
So it will be SPFX web parts for booking and scrap Outlook for the booking part.
Bookings go straight into Outlook and SP Online Calendars since this is already built for us.
We can also send booking info to any other SharePoint page or web part if need be.
Bookings would then be visible in Outlook.

We do any amendments in a SharePoint online form - custom built or in PowerApps.

My question is:
Is this logical? Is it a good proposal? Is it future proof? Can the Windows Service work in Azure maybe on a VM? Can the Windows Service also work 
with SPO?
I think current stack (Win 2012, Windows Service, and SP 2013) will be dated due to Office and SP online APIs
getting updates very frequently by MS and we have no view of updates sometimes until failure on end client/end application.
Also our Win server 2012 boxes will come to End of Life soon.

Does it need to be a separate service again? I don't know but doesn't have to. Do we have to have a Windows Service? Ideally no but I don't want to be biased since am a web guy! ;-)

Any thoughts? All advice and direction is much appreciated.

I have full stack experience and prefer Node and .NET web apps but not desktop or windows apps.